# Problemas con el documento de log en mosquitto

Tags: server, mqtt

Tengo dos preguntas principalmente

1. Como puedo obtener el archivo de log del broker mosquitto, he hecho esta configuración pero no puedo encontrar el archivo donde se recopila la información por ningún lado?
2. De que manera puedo arrancar el broker de mosquitto de manera que no sea un servicio de Windows?

Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo y que tengan un buen día.

```
Mosquitto conf. file
# Note that if the broker is running as a Windows service it will default to
# "log_dest none" and neither stdout nor stderr logging is available.
# Use "log_dest none" if you wish to disable logging.
#log_dest none 
log_dest topic 
log_dest syslog 
log_dest file C:\Archivos de programa\mosquitto\mosquitto.log
```

Comment: Para la primera pregunta, hay que contrapreguntar: versión de mosquitto y si ves algún error al iniciar el servicio. Así mismo, confirmar que se tienen permisos para generar el log allá (windows puede estar bloqueando eso); yo intentaría generarlo en algún lugar que no tenga tantos controles del OS (una carpeta nueva `c:\Workspace\mosquitto\mosquitto.log`)

Comment: La versión que estoy usando es la 1.6.10a ,Entonces no es necesario crear la ruta dentro de la carpeta de mosquito? podría usar esta por ejemplo:  ""C:\MOSQ\mosquitto.log"?

Comment: Es una ruta absoluta; va a funcionar siempre y cuando tengas permiso

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a la primera pregunta: yo actualizaría la versión a 1.6.12b o posterior teniendo en cuenta [este bug](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1880) que causaba líos en la generación de logs sobre Windows.

La respuesta a la segunda pregunta: `mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf` asumiendo que la ruta al exe está en el PATH

Comment: MI ruta para de mi exe es esta ""C:\Archivos de programa\mosquitto"", ese comando que me acabas de mencionar se escribe en el cmd en modo de administrador ?

Comment: Siempre depende de los permisos que tengas. Debería funcionar con tu usuario a menos que esté muy restringido :)

Comment: oh ok,  pregunte eso porque esta es la manera que encontré de arrancar el broker y es como lo he estado haciendo desde entonces https://youtu.be/72u6gIkeqUc

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf
"mosquitto.exe" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\WINDOWS\system32> ---------------------------------------------------------Al pacerer no se recocnoce como un comando o documento, que puedo estar haciendo mal ?

Comment: Por eso te dije que la ruta al exe debe estar en el PATH.

Comment: oh ok, hay manera de cambiarla ?

Comment: Edita el PATH de tu usuario y añade la ruta al exe. PD. Edité la respuesta

Comment: Ya agregue la ruta al PATH de Windows, pero ahora me aparece esta mensaje al momento ejecutar el comando que me diste---------------------------------------------Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf
1623358580: Error: Unable to open config file mosquitto.conf.

Comment: Tienes que darle la ruta completa al archivo conf...

Comment: te refieres a algo como esto ?-------------------------------------------------------------"C:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf", ese es la ruta de mi archivo conf y sigue saliendo error cuando ejecuto el comando que me diste